# GAS: Error 401 while connecting to an API

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm trying to connect to Cloud Waitress API, a solution for restaurants,

Documentation: https://apidocs.cloudwaitress.com/#orderpromos

It's documentation gives an example on how to connect to the API:

```
curl https://api.cloudwaitress.com/v1/orders \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY" \ 
  -d `
    {
      "restaurant_id": "xxxxxxx",
      "limit": 10,
      "page": 1,
      "sort": { "created": -1 },
    }
```

I tried to create a Script in GAS to get the information back to a Spreadsheet.

Based on this question:

[How curl maps onto Google App Script URLFetchApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825877/how-curl-maps-onto-google-app-script-urlfetchapp)

I have changed my code as follows:

```
function getAuthHeader(){
  var apiKey = "SOME-API-KEY";
  var authHeader = Utilities.base64Encode(apiKey);
  return {
    headers: {Authorization: authHeader}
   }
}

function GetOrders(){  
  var url = "https://api.cloudwaitress.com/v1/orders";  
  
  var data = {
    "restaurant_id":"SOME-RESTAURANT-ID",
    "limit": 10,
    "page": 1,
    "sort": { "created": 1 }
  };
  
  var result = goPost(url ,data);

}

function goPost(url,data){
   var options = {
   'method' : 'post',
   'payload' : data,
   'headers': getAuthHeader()['headers']
   };
  
   var response; 
  
   try{
     response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getContentText());
   }catch(err){
    Logger.log(err);
   }
  
   return response;
 }
```

Right now the new error that I'm getting is:

> Exception: Request failed for https://api.cloudwaitress.com returned
> code 401. Truncated server response: {"outcome":1,"message":"Invalid
> Authentication"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full
> response)

Which I believe is quite a progress since I was getting an 500 error before.

[image]

I have asked the cloudwaitress team their assistance, however I wonder if there is something else I can try.

Comment: Luis, could you please cross-link to your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62135141/gas-error-500-while-connecting-to-an-api/62215358#62215358) for others to be able to take note that the old one is answered here by Tanaike? I nearly gave a duplicate answer as though that your question is still unanswered (maybe we should vote the older as duplicate for it to point here?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- At your sample curl, `"Content-Type: application/json"` is used, and the JSON object is converted to the string.
- The [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53825877/7108653) you refered uses the basic authorization like `-u testtoken123:`. By this, `Utilities.base64Encode` is required be used. But in your sample curl, the API key is directly used.

  - I thought that this might be the reason of the error message.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var options = {
'method' : 'post',
'payload' : data,
'headers': getAuthHeader()['headers']
};
```

To:

```
var apiKey = "SOME-API-KEY";
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
  'headers': {Authorization: apiKey},
  'contentType': "application/json",
};
```

- In this case, `getAuthHeader()` is not used.

#### Note:

- The request of this modified script is the same with your sample curl command. But in this modified script, it supposes that your `apiKey` and `data` can be used for this API. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: Worked out great. Thanks Tanaike!
I lack the basics in these kind of topics..

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.